# change the Label text in runtime inside a panel

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I am creating List of Panel. Each panel Contain a Label  and Button . I have also a Button(button1). I want to change  the label text of (panels[0]) when click button1. How can I do this.This is my c# code:

```
List<Panel> panels = new List<Panel>();    
 private void Panel()
            {

                var x = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
                {
                    x += 60;
                    var panel1 = new Panel() { Size = new Size(60, 140), Location = new Point(x, 100), BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle };
                    panel1.Name = "pan" + i;


                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Name = "lbl" + i;
                    lbl.Text = i.ToString();
                    lbl.Location = new Point(10, 20);
                    panel1.Controls.Add(lbl);

                    Button button = new Button();
                    button.Location = new Point(10, 90);
                    button.Size = new Size(40, 40);
                    button.Text = "Click";

                    panel1.Controls.Add(button);



                    panels.Add(panel1);
                    Controls.Add(panel1);
                }
            }






     private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



            foreach (var p in panels)
            {


            }



        }
```

Output:

[image]

But i want, When i Click button1 it will change Label text of zero index panels(I have pointed it using red mark).

[image]

Can anyone help me...

Comment: You forgot to give the button a Click event handler.  A lambda will work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so you've got a button and a label within a panel. When you click a button of a panel, you wanna do something to the label in the same panel, right ?

So

```
private void BtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  var button = (Button)sender;//you've got the button clicked
  var panel = button.Parent;//you've got the panel.
  //var label = panel.Controls.OfType<Label>().FirstOrDefault();//but don't think you get this in c# 3.0
  var label = GetFirstLabel(panel);
  if (label != null)
     label.Text = "something";
}

private Label GetFirstLabel(Control parent) {
   foreach (var control in parent.Controls) {
       if (control is Label) return control as Label;
   }
   return null;
}
```

Usage

When you add your buttons, you can now do

```
 Button button = new Button();
 button.Location = new Point(10, 90);
 button.Size = new Size(40, 40);
 button.Text = "Click";
 button.Click += BtnClick;
```

And this will work on all panels.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't store reference to that `Label` then you can find it in controls of the first `Panel` by type for example:

```
panels[0].Controls.OfType<Label>().First().Text = "New Text";
```

or by name

```
panels[0].Controls.OfType<Label>().Single(l => l.Name == "lbl1").Text = "New Text";
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this with a simple method:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label l = panels[0].Controls.Find("lbl1", false).FirstOrDefault() as Label;
    l.Text = "TEXT";
}
```